# Mysql 8 Aggregation

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregation, mysql-8.0

I have a table with this specific structure

[image]

Here, we have serval actions that are performed by different candidates (`performer`).
For each performance, it can be primary or secondary (`primary` column).

Every action can be performed primarily just once, but can be secondary serval times

What I am looking for, is a result where I get for every action, the name of the primary performer, and the names of the secondary performers.

Here is the result I am looking for:

[image]

Can this be done just by an SQL script? Or I have to develop a back end script (using PHP for example) to format the data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it can be done easily, like this:

```
SELECT  action,
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            CASE
                WHEN T.primary = 1
                THEN performer
            END
        )                   AS  primary,
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            CASE
                WHEN T.primary = 0
                THEN performer
            END
        )                   AS  secondary
FROM    my_table
GROUP BY action
```

Comment: There is only 1 row with primary = 1 for every action, so no need for GROUP_CONCAT() for this. A simple MAX(CASE...) will do.

Comment: it was not clear in the question if primary can appear only once, but even so, I suggest to use GROUP_CONCAT when working with string

Comment: @forpas The answer given by Yair Maron gets the job done. Do you please have another suggestion using MAX(CASE..) ? Thank you all

Comment: @beta-developper it's rather a simplification and not another solution: `MAX(CASE                WHEN T.primary = 1 THEN performer END)` instead of GROUP_CONCAT()